# How to evaluate $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{a^2 + b^2 \sin^2 x}{b^2 + a^2 \cos^2 x} \tan x \, dx \, db \, da $

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> $$
> \Omega = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{a^2 + b^2 \sin^2 x}{b^2 + a^2 \cos^2 x} \tan x \, dx \, db \, da
> $$

$$
\Omega_1 = \int_0^{\frac\pi4} \frac{a^2 + b^2 \sin^2 x}{b^2 + a^2 \cos^2 x} \tan x \, dx \quad \text{(let } t = \tan x \text{)}
$$
$$
= \int_0^1 \frac{a^2 + (a^2 + b^2) t^2}{b^2 + a^2 + b^2 t^2} \cdot \frac{t}{1 + t^2} \, dt
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{a^2 + (a^2 + b^2) t}{(a^2 + b^2 + b^2 t)(1 + t)} \, dt
$$
$$
= \frac{a^4 + b^4 + a^2 b^2}{2a^2 b^2} \int_0^1 \frac{b^2}{a^2 + b^2 + b^2 t} \, dt - \frac{b^2}{2a^2} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + t} \, dt
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{2} \left( \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2 + 1 \right) \log \left(1 + \frac{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2}{1 + \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2} \right) - \frac{\log(2)}{2} \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Too long for comment*

While the direction you've taken will probably work out just fine, we may also consider integrating w.r.t. $a$ or $b$ first. We have for instance

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{a^2 + b^2\sin^2x}{a^2\cos^2x + b^2} \tan x &= \sec^2x \tan x + b^2 \frac{\left(\sin^2x-\sec^2x\right)\tan x}{a^2\cos^2x+b^2} \\
\implies \int_0^1 \cdots da &= \sec^2x \tan x + b^2 \int_0^1 \frac{\tan^3x-\sec^4x\tan x}{a^2+b^2\sec^2x} \, da \\
&= \sec^2x \tan x + b \left(\tan^2x-\sec^4x\right)\sin x \arctan\left(\frac{\cos x}b\right)
\end{align*}$$

The integral w.r.t. $b$ can be done by parts, and the subsequent $x$-integral can be expanded into several trivial integrals plus a linear combination of integrals of the form $(n\in\{0,1,2,3\})$

$$\int_0^{\tfrac\pi4} \arctan(\cos x) \cos(2nx) \sec^3x \tan x \, dx$$

It's likely tedious work, but these should be doable by applying Leibniz's integral rule to

$$I(\alpha) = \int_0^{\tfrac\pi4} \arctan(\alpha\cos x) \cos(2nx) \sec^3x \tan x \, dx$$